# Getting an AttributeError in Python code (while inheriting from Parent class) - Assignment 30 of Object Oriented Programming (INFYTQ)

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, aggregation

I'm practicing some object-oriented assignments and in this, I want to inherit the private attribute of the parent class. I want to check this with some conditions. Is there any way I can extract the value of private attribute via inheritance. I used the getter method but still getting an error.

I am following this class diagram:
[image: class diagram]

```py
class Pizzaservice:
    counter = 100
    def __init__(self, customer, pizza_type, additional_topping):
        self.__service_id = None
        self.__customer = customer
        self.__pizza_type = pizza_type
        self.__additional_topping = additional_topping  #boolean (T=req)
        self.pizza_cost = None
    def validate_pizza_type(self):
        if(self.get_pizza_type() == "Small" or self.get_pizza_type() == "Medium"):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    def calculate_pizza_cost(self):
        a = self.validate_pizza_type()
        b = self.__customer.validate_quantity()
        if(a == True and b == True):
            q = self.__customer.get_quantity()
            if(self.__pizza_type == "Small"):
                if(self.__additional_topping == True):
                    self.pizza_cost = (150 + 35) * q
                else:
                    self.pizza_cost = 150 * q
            elif(self.__pizza_type == "Medium"):
                if(self.__additional_topping == True):
                    self.pizza_cost = (200 + 50) * q
                else:
                    self.pizza_cost = 200 * q

            Pizzaservice.counter += 1
            self.__service_id = self.__pizza_type[0:1] + str(Pizzaservice.counter)
        else:
            self.pizza_cost = -1

    def get_service_id(self):
        return self.__service_id
    def get_pizza_type(self):
        return self.__pizza_type
    def get_customer(self):
        return self.__customer
    def get_additional_topping(self):
        return self.__additional_topping

class Doordelivery(Pizzaservice):
    def __init__(self, customer, pizza_type, additional_topping, distance_in_kms):
        self.__delivery_charge = None
        self.__distance_in_kms = distance_in_kms
    def validate_distance_in_kms(self):
        if(self.__distance_in_kms >=1 and self.__distance_in_kms <=10):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    def calculate_pizza_cost(self):
        d = self.validate_distance_in_kms()
        if(d == True):
            temp = super().calculate_pizza_cost()
            if(temp != -1):
                if(self.__distance_in_kms <= 5):
                    self.__delivery_charge = 5 * self.__distance_in_kms
                    self.pizza_cost = self.pizza_cost + self.__delivery_charge
                else:
                    self.__delivery_charge = 25 + (7 * (self.__distance_in_kms - 5))
                    self.pizza_cost = self.pizza_cost + self.__delivery_charge
            else:
                self.pizza_cost = -1
    def get_delivery_charge(self):
        return self.__delivery_charge
    def get_distance_in_kms(self):
        return self.__distance_in_kms

class Customer:
    def __init__(self, customer_name, quantity):
        self.__customer_name = customer_name
        self.__quantity = quantity
    def validate_quantity(self):
        if(self.__quantity >= 1 and self.__quantity <= 5):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    def get_customer_name(self):
        return self.__customer_name
    def get_quantity(self):
        return self.__quantity

c = Customer("Sanya", 2)
obj_1 = Pizzaservice(c, "Small", True)
obj_2 = Doordelivery(c, "Small", True, 2)
obj_1.calculate_pizza_cost()
obj_2.calculate_pizza_cost()
```

I am getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    line 89, in 
>      obj_2.calculate_pizza_cost()
>   line 56, in calculate_pizza_cost
>     temp = super().calculate_pizza_cost()
>   line 15, in calculate_pizza_cost
>     a = self.validate_pizza_type()
>   line 10, in validate_pizza_type
>     if(self.get_pizza_type() == "Small" or self.get_pizza_type() == "Medium"):
>   line 38, in get_pizza_type
>     return self.__pizza_type
>   AttributeError: 'Doordelivery' object has no attribute'_Pizzaservice__pizza_type'

Am I not understanding the inheritance part? What procedure should I follow to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, since you are defining a new constructor that's different from the parent class, you are overriding the `__init__` function. This is why the variable couldn't be found, because the parent class constructor was not called! You need to call `super().__init__(...)` to also initialise the variables you defined in the parent class.

Comment: Thank you so much. I get the first part of your answer. But one thing I am confused about, should I call `super().__init__(...)` within the `__init__()` function of the base class i.e. Doordelivery class? I am already overriding that method. So, Is it okay to call that (parent's init function) again?

Comment: Short answer: yes. Long answer: right now because you overrode the parent constructor, the setting of the variables is not done, which is why you get that the object doesn't have an attribute. You have to call the parent constructor to do the initialisation.